# How to add original account (address) to new mining rig

Tags: mining, addresses

I think I have some basic misunderstanding of how this all works.

I setup a mining rig on one pc, and created an address.

Say I get another mining rig. I do not want to create a new address, I want to use the old one.

So then I will have two systems mining into one account.

How do I attach the original address to a new pc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your original rig, under the datadir, there is a keystore subdirectory.
Copy it over and the new rig should get the account.  You probably want to copy the whole datadir too, since it will have the whole blockchain, so that the new rig doesn't have to start from scratch.

The default datadir is:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
Linux: ~/.ethereum
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum
```

Answer (score 2):

When mining you do not need any account. It is enough to set an address where the reward will go.

From geth help:

> --etherbase "0"       Public address for block mining rewards (default = first account created)

You can set the `etherbase` to the address of the account you have on the first machine or any other account you own.